# iTextSharp - Read also Second Page

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm new here. I am writing a program and use itextsharp. I would like to import various documents and then save them. Unfortunately I do not get it, the second page is read. The editing of the first page kappt super. Here is my code:

```
       If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "DPD" Then


        Dim oldFile As String = "templates/dpd-schadenformular.pdf"
        Dim newFile As String = "output/DPD-Output.pdf"

        ' Create reader
        Dim reader As New PdfReader(oldFile)
        Dim size As Rectangle = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)
        Dim document As New Document(size)

        ' Create the writer
        Dim fs As New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs)
        document.Open()
        Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent

        ' Set the font, color and size properties for writing text to the PDF
        Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY)
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8)

        ' Write text in the PDF
        cb.BeginText()

        Dim kundennummer As String = "Kundennummer " & Form3.dpdkdnr.Text

        Dim trackid1 As String = track1.Text
        Dim trackid2 As String = track2.Text

        Dim descr As String = beschreibungschaden.Text
        Dim warenart As String = paketinhalt.Text

        Dim empfnam As String = empfnamebox.Text
        Dim empfstr As String = empfstrbox.Text
        Dim empfplz As String = empfplzbox.Text





        ' Set the alignment and coordinates here
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, kundennummer, 360, 638, 0)

        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, trackid1, 336, 685, 0)
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, trackid2, 430, 685, 0)

        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, descr, 150, 135, 0)
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, warenart, 90, 235, 0)

        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, empfnam, 370, 441, 0)
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, empfstr, 370, 416, 0)
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, empfplz, 370, 381, 0)



        cb.EndText()

        ' Put the text on a new page in the PDF 
        Dim page As PdfImportedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1)
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0)

        ' Close the objects
        document.Close()
        fs.Close()
        writer.Close()
        reader.Close()


        ' -----------------------------------------------
        ' -----------------------------------------------
        ' --------------------- DPD Ende ----------------
        ' -----------------------------------------------
        ' -----------------------------------------------

    End If
```

About approaches, solutions or help I would be really very happy and thank you in advance

Maurice

Comment: **A** Using `PdfWriter` for merging pages from different documents usually is a bad choice; instead `PdfCopy` should be used (it even allows stamping on copied pages). **B** If for some reason your case is an exception to the rule and `PdfWriter`use is appropriate, use `document.NewPager()` and probably a loop.

Comment: Wow thank you for the fast feedback :) Because I have not so much experience, could you build me an example? `Thank you in advance :(

Comment: The last time I did VB coding was in the late 1990s. Thus, I'm afraid I'm not the guy to quickly build some VB example...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I use to add new pages to a destination document.

```
 'myarray is the document to be added,   mydoc is the document added to   

Public Function AdddbFiletoDoc(myarray() As Byte, mydoc As Document, mywriter As PdfWriter, mycb As PdfContentByte)
    Dim myreader As New PdfReader(myarray)
    Dim numofPages As Integer = myreader.NumberOfPages, mypage As PdfImportedPage
    Dim currpage As Integer = 0
    Do While currpage < numofPages
        currpage += 1
        mydoc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4)
'You can add a flag to the method to determine if you want a new page or not
        mydoc.NewPage()
        mypage = mywriter.GetImportedPage(myreader, currpage)
        mycb.AddTemplate(mypage, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0)
    Loop

End Function
```

Comment: thank you haim katz, my problem is, unfortunately, that the source has pdf 2 sides and I would like to simply read these and would like to store them on it. I'm not a profi in visual basic. If anyone had a 1: 1 solution I would be really grateful.

Comment: I don't understand where your are storing the pdf.  In the database?  on the same page?